# using struct pack and unpack on floating point number 0.01 output 0.009999999776482582.

Tags: python

using 'struct pack and unpack' on floating point number 0.01 outputs 0.009999999776482582. 
For my project I would have to configure values which are float
and the same needs to be stored in binary file and I would need this data to analyze later and I need the exact values that was configured.

Can some one help me if there is any way that I could store the exact value 0.01 and retrieve the same.

Based on some of the post I have already tried using double instead of float and it works but the problem with using double is my file size increases. I have a lot of parameters which is float and can take values any where between 0 to 5. 
Hence any other suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is the sample code

```
import struct
a = 0.01
b = struct.pack('<f', a)
c = struct.unpack('<f', b)
print c
(0.009999999776482582,)
```

Comment: The exact value `0.01` is not representable by a float. Perhaps you could look at the `decimal` module if you want to represent `0.01` exactly.

Comment: What kind of values are you storing? You say that numbers go from 0 to 5, how many decimal places?

Comment: "Based on some of the post I have already tried using double instead of float and it works but the problem with using double is my file size increases" - if you're not willing to pay the storage price to hold all the precision you need, you shouldn't complain about precision loss in your output.

Comment: You have to either pick and chose which fields in the file the precision matters and use `'f'` and `'d'` appropriately, OR you need to live with either the loss of precision or the bigger file.

Comment: If all of your parameters are real numbers in a narrow range with a fixed number of decimal places, perhaps you could multiply each of them by an appropriate power of 10 and store the resulting integers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no floating point number `0.01`. IEEE floating point numbers do not represent the entire real number line; they represent an approximation using a particular binary scheme. The closest approximation has the decimal representation 0.009999999776482582.

You could try serializing a textual representation (e.g. json) or pickle a BigDecimal which can represent arbitrary precisions.

Answer (score 2):

You say that numbers go from 0 to 5. If you only need two decimal places (0.00, 0.01, ..., 5.00) then you can store the numbers as 16 bit integers, first by multiplying the number by 100, and then when reading dividing the number by 100:

```
>>> import struct
>>> digits = 2
>>> a = 0.01
>>> b = struct.pack('<H', int(round(a, digits)) * (10 ** digits))
>>> c = struct.unpack('<H', b)
>>> print (c[0] / (10.0 ** digits))
0.01
```

Storing numbers with H format you can actually save 50% space compared to floats. If you need more precision, more than two decimal places, you need yo multiply the number and then dividing by 1000, 10000, etc, changing the format from H to I.

Comment: `int(a * 100)` will round down, which can give the wrong result if `a` is 0.009999999.

Comment: The main condition for this trick to work is to have numbers with at most two, and only two, significant digits. This means that I don't expect to have numbers like 0.009. That's why I asked the kind of numbers he is handling.

Comment: The numbers are floating-point, so inaccuracies can, and will, cause numbers like 0.01 to be turned into 0.0099999999. You should round to the nearest number instead of rounding down.

Comment: I don't like rounding... anyway, you're probably right.

Comment: This is rolling your own fixed-point representation. Which is fine in so far as it goes, but one already exists.

Comment: Yes, because OP doesn't want to use doubles for space storage reasons. Therefore we need to do this. An alternative is to store the floats as rationals.